# OpenMP C Normal Random Generator

Tags: c, random, openmp, gaussian

I was doing a C assignment for parallel computing, where I have to implement some sort of Monte Carlo simulations with efficient tread safe normal random generator using Box-Muller transform. I generate 2 vectors of uniform random numbers X and Y, with condition that X in (0,1] and Y in [0,1].
But I'm not sure that my way of sampling uniform random numbers from the halfopen interval (0,1] is right.
Did anyone encounter something similar?
I'm using following Code:

```
double* StandardNormalRandom(long int N){
    double *X = NULL, *Y = NULL, *U = NULL;

    X = vUniformRandom_0(N / 2);
    Y = vUniformRandom(N / 2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i<N/2; i++){
            U[2*i] = sqrt(-2 * log(X[i]))*sin(Y[i] * 2 * pi);
            U[2*i + 1] = sqrt(-2 * log(X[i]))*cos(Y[i] * 2 * pi);
            }
    return U;
    }

    double* NormalRandom(long int N, double mu, double sigma2)
    {
            double *U = NULL, stdev = sqrt(sigma2);
            U = StandardNormalRandom(N);
            #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) U[i] = mu + stdev*U[i];
            return U;
    }
```

here is the bit of my UniformRandom function also implemented in parallel:

```
#pragma omp parallel for  firstprivate(i)
for (long int j = 0; j < N;j++)
{
    if (i == 0){
        int tn = omp_get_thread_num();
        I[tn] = S[tn];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        I[j] = (a*I[j - 1] + c) % m;
    }

}

}
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (long int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    U[j] = (double)I[j] / (m+1.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `StandardNormalRandom` function, I will assume that the pointer `U` has been allocated to the size `N`, in which case this function looks fine to me.
As well as the function `NormalRandom`.

However for the function `UniformRandom` (which is missing some parts, so I'll have to assume some stuff), if the following line `I[j] = (a*I[j - 1] + c) % m + 1;` is the body of a loop with a `omp parallel for`, then you will have some issues. As you can't know the order of execution of the thread, the current thread (with a fixed value of `j`) can't rely on the value of `I[j - 1]` as this value could be modified at any time (`I` should be shared by default).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not an issue, I initialise I[j] at the first execution of the thread and give it value from the array of random numbers I generated before.

Comment: @Suren Ok, could you edit your question with the missing code. It will be easier for people to help you.